# SpringBoot, controller return data through ResponseBodyAdvice occur an error (class can't cast to string)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want format controller's result by using ResponseBodyAdvice.
For example, controller method return a string ("hello"), the ResponseBodyAdvice format it as a Json data {code:1, data:"hello"}.

Here is my controller method code:

```
@PostMapping("login")
public String login(String username, String pwd) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(username + pwd);
    return "hhh";
}
```

Here is my ResponseBodyAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        return TResult.success(o); // result is my class, it occur error
        // return JSON.toJSONString(TResult.success(o)); // result is string, it's ok
    }
}
```

the error message is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cn.tianyu.blog_api.util.TResult cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.getContentLength(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:43) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.addDefaultHeaders(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:259) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:210) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:275) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

the result is 
[image]

TResult.class

```
public class TResult {

private Integer code;
private String message;
private Object data;

public TResult() {
}

public TResult(Integer code, String message) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
}

public static TResult success() {
    TResult result = new TResult();
    result.setResultCode(TResultCode.SUCCESS);
    return result;
}

public static TResult success(Object data) {
    TResult result = new TResult();
    result.setResultCode(TResultCode.SUCCESS);
    result.setData(data);
    return result;
}
```

Note the return type in the direction of the red arrow.
The final result type is application/json, I set a breakpoints, the method "ResponseBodyAdvice.beforeBodyWrite()" was called two times. The error happened for the first time. Assembled error message for the second time.

please help! thank you very much!

Comment: Post the relevant code of `TResult` (including possibly `success` method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I know the reason.
Spring will use corresponding HttpMessageConvert by method return value.
When method return String.class, String will use StringHttpMessageConvert.class to handler the result.
But StringHttpMessageConvert only support String.class, and I change it to TResult.class (in GlobalControllerAdvice.class, see question), so it occur error.
Here is two ways to solve it:
1: Rewrite StringHttpMessageConvert, This way is more complicated.
2: Don't change the return class in GlobalControllerAdvice.class, change the return value(in json format) only, I used this way

Here  is the code:

```
public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
    TResult result = TResult.success(o);
    // just change the value
    if (o instanceof String) {
        return JSON.toJSONString(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
public boolean supports(final MethodParameter methodParameter,
                        final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
    return !aClass.equals(StringHttpMessageConverter.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly irrelevant, but I learnt most of what I know from SO by leaning slightly irrelevant to what I was looking for, so assuming it will help you.

[ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) was built for that exact reason - wrap the response with some metadata. With it, you could

1. add custom headers
2. handle errors
3. handle auth
4. go easy on UI.

Here is a [sample](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity) for you to get started. Your `login` method would look like

```
@PostMapping("login")
public ResponseEntity<String> `@ResponseBody` login(String username, String pwd) throws Exception {
    // if invalid return new ResponseEntity<>("Oops!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome " + username);
}
```

Hope you have fun with'em, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Understood what you are trying to implement as I did the same recently. If you wish to customize the response along with its class type (as against the one specified in your controller return type), then you can use class generics while implementing ResponseBodyAdvice.
Note: you have used ResponseBodyAdvice as against the expected ***`ResponseBodyAdvice <Object>` ***

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalControllerAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

     @Override
        public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class aClass) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
            JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
            responseObj.put("code1", TResult.success(o);
            return responseObj;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide verbal explanation on how you came up with this solution and what it does. Thank you.